# how to use javascript ui libraries with dart

Tags: jquery-ui, dart, dart-js-interop

Dart widget is really poor when we compare will all the widget of jquery-ui and it's plugin.

I don't found widget similar to jqgrid.

Except waiting then dart have a lot of widget, is there a way to use other javascript library?

Comment: Take a look at questions/answers filed under the dart-js-interop tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any js lib with [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-js). See [Using JavaScript from Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/).